# Find out where in browser history the user is

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I know I access browser history using `history` object, specifically, I can use `history.back();`, `history.forward();` and `history.go(item-number)` (or `history.go(url)`). What I am trying to determine where in the browser history the user currently is.

Firefox, for example, may support accessing individual url's from the history, but that's not what I'm after, because the history of 20 url's may contain repeated url's.

Note that I am not interested in a history within my project - but rather browser history within any user's session.

For example, a user opened the browser and went through 20 pages - so the history contains 20 objects.  Then the user hit *back* button 4 times - and ended up on the 16th of the 20 pages (or rather 15th of the 0..19 pages).  Is there any way to get this current offset (16 or 15) using JavaScript?  If yes, then how?

Comment: Out of interest, what do you want to use this information for?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, I know about that.  It doesn't answer my question though.

Comment: It answers the question saying, nothing in the docs gives you that data. :) And comments are not answers. They ask for and/or give more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
history.length
```

returns the length of the current history.

sadly there is **no** method to figure out where in it you are.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this will help, but with HTML5 you can add a state object to each item in the browser history list. This gives you a possible way to save each item's index (i.e., its `history.length` value at the time it is first created), which you can then examine later.

This is the only solution I found that worked for me.

See [my solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017791/#32019654) for more details.

Comment: thats only possible in single page applications that use pushstate accordingly. this is not what OP wants: "Note that I am not interested in a history within my project - but rather browser history within any user's session."