# How to find the current location index in the browser history

Tags: javascript

Browsers provide a list of the pages visited within a client session through the `window.history` object. With this, client code can navigate forwards and backwards through the list (using `history.back()`, `history.forward()`, and `history.go()`).

But how can the client code determine *where* in the history the current page is located? For example, if the client visits pages A, B, and C, the history will contain three items, and the current history item (or state) will be for page C. If the user then clicks the 'back' button, the current page is now B. However, the `history.length` is still 3, reflecting the fact that three pages were visited in total. How do we determine that the client is currently at item 2 in the history?

A more specific problem is that I want to determine if I am positioned at the first item in the history, so that I can display a 'Close' button which will close the page (assuming that `window.opener` is not null); at any other position in the history, I want to display a 'Back' button instead which will navigate to the previous page.

This seems to be a curious omission that there is no 'current index' into the history object.

*Note: This is similar to [question #12895940](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895940), but differs in that I really only need to know if I am positioned at the first location in the history.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out where in browser history the user is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895940/find-out-where-in-browser-history-the-user-is)

Comment: As it was said in the topic above (@duskwuff), I think there is no way to do this in JavaScript, unless you create something like a web extension to keep track of the history "all the time". But I bet this isn't the solution you're looking for

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only thing I came up with (which only works in HTML5+ browsers) is something along the lines of this:

```
// Onload
{
    if (!history.state  &&  typeof(history.replaceState) == "function")
        history.replaceState({ page: history.length, href: location.href }, "foo");
}
```

This pushes a state object onto the history stack when the page first loads. (The `typeof` check is needed to ensure that the browser supports the HTML5 `replaceState()` method.)

Later, I can check if the current history object is the first one in the list that got replaced:

```
if (history.state  &&  history.state.page == 1) {
    // It appears that we are positioned at the first history item
    ...
}
```

This seems to be adequate for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

To support pre HTML5 browsers you can add a query parameter to the url, for example: `mysite.com?i=0` for the first page, `i=1` when they navigate to the next page etc.

When the user hits the back button, you can retrieve the value of i with `window.location.search` and modify your page with a close/back button accordingly.